# Set android alarm and it does't show at the right time

Tags: android

i set an alarm and set time when it is going to start,but the alarm started with a few minutes or seconds delayed.I use the setWindow on android 4.4+ and it is all of no use,how to make it start at the right time.

```
public class AlarmSetActivity extends Activity {

private Context context;
private AlarmManager manager;
private Intent intent;
private PendingIntent pi;
@ViewInject(R.id.activity_content_tv)
private TextView title;
@ViewInject(R.id.time_set_btn)
private Button timeSetBtn;
@ViewInject(R.id.time_set_open_che)
private CheckBox timeSetOpenCheck;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm_set);
    ViewUtils.inject(this);
    context = this;
    manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    title.setText("闹钟设置 ");
    intent = new Intent(context, AlarmNotifyReceiver.class);
    pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    if (!timeSetOpenCheck.isChecked()) {
        manager.cancel(pi);
    }
}

@OnClick({ R.id.time_set_btn, R.id.alarm_voice_set, R.id.back_btn,
        R.id.voice_set_btn })
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.time_set_btn:
        if (timeSetOpenCheck.isChecked()) {
            setTime();
        }
        break;
    case R.id.back_btn:
        onBackPressed();
        break;
    case R.id.alarm_voice_set:
        setAlarmRingtone();
        break;
    case R.id.voice_set_btn:
        setAlarmRingtone();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case 1:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = data
                    .getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
            RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context,
                    RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM, uri);
        }
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}

/**
 * 闹钟的时间选择
 */
private void setTime() {
    // 弹出设置时间的窗口
    new TimeDialog(context).setTime(timeSetBtn);
}

/**
 * 选择闹钟铃声
 */
private void setAlarmRingtone() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE,
            RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_SILENT, false);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "请选择闹钟铃声");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
```

Comment: Use the `AlarmManager#setExact()` method if you want it to fire at a specific time.

Comment: still not run  exactly

Comment: Then provide us with a [mcve]. Nobody wants to dig through pages of code to find out why.

Answer (score 0):

You did not set the second. So the alarm will start at current second in the time you set and it seems to be delayed